# R parallel on multi-CPU Windows machine

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Will R properly recognize all the cores on a **multi-CPU** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit  machine? We are designing a parallel computing system with Intel CPUs, using two CPUs on one mainboard. There will be a total of 32 cores between the 2 CPUs (8 physical cores per CPU, up to 16 logical cores per CPU).

Before we spend the money, I want some confirmation that my R code will recognize and access all (or nearly all) the cores (usually, I put all but 1 into a cluster). I am using R doParallel and foreach packages successfully on a Win 10 Pro 64-bit workstation with a single 4-core CPU with 8 logical cores. I can run my R code and request 7 cores with no trouble.

Comment: You can also use the windows linux subsystem to run native ubuntu.  There are more parallel options in R on linux, and little overhead to running the subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use all of your cores in R. R successfully recognizes all available cores on both my laptop and my data science server.

Once you have access to one of the computers you want to use, you can find out how many cores R recognizes with the `detectCores()` function from the `parallel` package.

```
library(parallel)
detectCores()
```

Taking a step back, you might want to reconsider the architecture of your system. If you have to run something so intense that it requires a battalion of multithreaded machines, you might want to think about rewriting your code to be more efficient or possibly integrate `Rcpp` or move to a different language.

Comment: I think he hasn't bought the computer yet.

Comment: @F.Privé Good point, I edited my answer to make it more generally applicable.